# Transition from one UIViewController to another in a custom segue

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uistoryboardsegue

This custom segue visually works correctly but there is an warning when completed.

```
Warning: Attempt to present <DestViewController: 0x21059f40> on <SrcViewController: 0x1fd50cf0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Any help on how to get this to work without the warning would be much appreciated, have spent more time on this than i should.  Not even sure if I should care about it since it is a warning.

```
- (void)perform {
    UIViewController *src = (UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *dst = (UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController;

    dst.view.alpha = 0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                     [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                     [src.view addSubview:dst.view];
                     dst.view.alpha = 1;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [dst.view removeFromSuperview];
                     //need to understand why this throws a warning but still works
                     [src presentViewController:dst animated:NO completion:^(){
                         [src reset];
                     }];
                 }];
}
```

**UPDATE**

There was a call to stop a MPMoviePlayerController in the reset method on the src UIViewController.  For some reason that was causing the issue, once removed this segue works perfectly.  See my answer below for final implementation of segue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although the original issue was caused by something outside of the segue, as mentioned above, i thought i would post the full working segue code for others who may end up here.  The delegate in this example is a custom UIViewController container where the child UIViewContainers where added as children in the following way:

```
[self addChildViewController:childController_];
[self.view addSubview:childController_.view];
```

segue.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface COFSimpleSegue : UIStoryboardSegue

@property (assign) UIViewController *delegate;

@end
```

segue.m

```
#import "COFSimpleSegue.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation COFSimpleSegue

@synthesize delegate = delegate_;

- (void)perform {
    UIViewController *src = (UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *dst = (UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController;

    dst.view.frame = delegate_.view.bounds;
    dst.view.autoresizingMask = delegate_.view.autoresizingMask;

    [src willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

    [delegate_
       transitionFromViewController:src
       toViewController:dst
       duration:0.5f
       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
       animations:^(void){}
       completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         [dst didMoveToParentViewController:delegate_];
         [src removeFromParentViewController];
       }
    ];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the view from superview i.e src.view and presenting the same viewController after it , so it is showing warning.

Try this (If this doesn't work tell me):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                     [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                     dst.view.alpha = 1;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [src presentViewController:dst animated:NO completion:^(){
                         [src reset];
                     }];
                 }];
}
```

Comment: it didn't help or hurt.  I removed the two lines of code and it works exactly the same and still gives the same warning.

Comment: Can you please provide what is written inside [src reset] ??

Comment: there was a call to stop a MPMoviePlayerController in reset.  once i got rid of that it worked.  I did need to put back the two lines of code for adding the dst view and then removing it in the complete block because the animation didn't happen otherwise.  thanks for your help.

Comment: i really do appreciate your help, but i am hesitant to accept your answer as the example code doesn't solve the issue and i don't want to confuse others who come across this.  Anyway to edit your answer so that it is more relevant to the actually solution?